# Error al mandar a imprimir

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo mandar a imprimir los public void imprimirAd,imprimirEm me marca un error al mandarlo a imprimirlo?

```
"""
Codio que se crea para las listas
"""

case 4: //Agregar elemento lista o arreglo 
                    Altas Alta1 = new Altas();
                    Alta1.imprimirAd(List < Admin > list);
                    break;

"""
Codigo que se crea para la segunda lista
"""

public void imprimirEm(List<Empresa> listEm) //imprimir empresa  
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listEm.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("/" + listEm[i]);
        }
    }

"""
Error al momento de mandar a imprimir ya que no reconoce las listas y pide un parametro ya que no imprime List <Admin> list)
"""

case 4: //Agregar elemento lista o arreglo 
                    Altas Alta1 = new Altas();
                    Alta1.imprimirAd(List < Admin > list);
                    break;
"""
Error al momento de mandar a imprimir ya que no reconoce las listas y pide un parametro ya que no imprime List < Empresa > listEm
"""
case 5:
                    Altas Alta2 = new Altas();
                    Alta2.imprimirEm(List < Empresa > listEm);
                    break;
```

Comment: El tipo de los parámetros se indica en la declaración de la función. Al llamar la función no lo tienes que hacer. Si tienes una función que recibe un entero `void ImprimirNumero(int numero) { Consolé.WriteLine(numero); }` la llamas pasando el número así `ImprimirNumero(5)`.

Comment: Cual es la estructura de los tipos de datoos Admin y Empresa

Comment: lo que pasa es que me marca El uso generico List<T>requiere argumentos tipo 1

Comment: por lo que no se puede mandar a imprimir

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Procura no llenar los comentarios, no es un chat y la idea es que te pidan aclaraciones acá. Abajo irán los intentos de respuesta. Lo otro: no has incluido el mensaje de error completo EN la pregunta. Edítala y ponlo EN la pregunta, por favor :)